# Adding a Second App (iTunes Connect)

Tags: xcode, itunes

I recently uploaded my first iPhone app to the App Store, and i'm thinking of creating a new app. I am wondering what new things I will need to create for it to be submitted. Examples: Bundle ID's, Certificates, or Provisioning Profiles, etc.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need everything you needed for the first app, except that your distribution certificate is a personal identity and lives in your keychain and at the Portal, so you only need one of those (until it expires, when you'll need to make a new one).

It might help if I make you a little chart here.

YOU: There is only one of you, so you only need one development certificate and one distribution certificate.

APP: Each app has its own bundle id and you'll need to tell that Portal what that is if you want to submit it to the store or hand it out in an ad hoc distribution.

PROFILE: A profile unites YOU and one APP. Thus it is unique to that APP and you'll need a new one for every APP you want to distribute. -- EXCEPTION: For convenience, Apple now allows you to develop many kinds of app on a device using a single **team development profile** where the APP is effectively a wild card. This was not always the case though; it used to be that you needed a new development profile for every app too, just as you need a new distribution profile for every app. And for apps with special needs you may still need a development profile just for that app.

Comment: May you please list all of the things I need? Sorry.

Comment: My book tells you all about it: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch09.html#_running_on_a_device and http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch09.html#_distribution

Comment: So, I would need a Development Provisioning Profile, Distribution Provisioning Profile, App ID, and a Bundle ID?

Comment: You don't need a Development anything to submit to the store. The store is Distribution. Pls read the chapter, OK?